# Is there a function in like re.findall but that returns dictionaries instead of tuples?

Tags: python, regex

Supose I have this string:

```
a= "hello world hella warld"
```

and I want to match all coincidences whit the regex:

```
b='(?P<hel>hell[oa])\s*(?P<wrl>w[oa]rld)'
```

I can use re.findall(b,a) and get:

```
[('hello', 'world'),('hella','warld')]
```

but I really want to get:

```
[{'hel':'hello','wrl':'world'},{'hel':'hella','wrl':'warld'}]
```

Mi queston is there some native or easy way to get this in Python?

**Second Question:**

I wrote a function to get dictionaries:

```
def findalldict(regex,line):
    matches = []
    match = 1
    c = line
    while match != None and len(c)>1:
        match =re.search(regex,c)
        if match:
            matches.append(match.groupdict())
            c =c[match.end():]
    return matches
```

but I'm no sure if it's correct, can you guys see any mistake? or you know a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead of `findall` to get an iterator of [`MatchObject`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject)s:

```
>>> regex = re.compile('(?P<hel>hell[oa])\s*(?P<wrl>w[oa]rld)')
>>> line = "hello world hella warld"
>>> [m.groupdict() for m in regex.finditer(line)]
[{'hel': 'hello', 'wrl': 'world'}, {'hel': 'hella', 'wrl': 'warld'}]
```